# Is it possible to solve a certain set of nonlinear equations in Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, nonlinear

I read this question in a Chinese forum last year. At the end of the discussion, they provide a solution of the equations from a C++ program. Unfortunately, they did not get the right answer.

```
Time consumption is 7 seconds 
Final loop number is 6 
Final solution is: 
-0.2322842682813542747386045948714 
-0.33451905509950505524842637422882 
0.69680689416256451699610476015703 
Final residue vector of nonlinear normal equation is: 
-1.1790595381573628784440805491522e-24 
-6.5283779960079553444986005481061e-25 
-4.5601874879475709938629551473305e-24 
Final tolx is: 
4.7551749192160155769219092621964e-24
```

Substitute the solutions into the equation, you will get a large residue, not as they claimed. Therefore, there must be something wrong there.

```
{f1, f2, f3} /. 
  {x -> -0.2322842682813542747386045948714,
   y -> -0.33451905509950505524842637422882, 
   z -> 0.69680689416256451699610476015703}
```

> ```
> {-2.27908518018606701394532153790*10^9, 
>  2.91065438564782615482450843594*10^8, 
>  3.50424506099962029337238135221*10^9}
> ```

What I want to ask here is how to solve this kind of ugly [Equations](http://att.newsmth.net/nForum/att/Mathematics/50845/346)? The equations are too ugly to be posted here, I just attach a link to the file.

Comment: Have you tried `Solve` or `NSolve`?

Comment: @Rahul Yes, no output in bearable time.

Comment: How about `FindRoot`?

Comment: Timing[NMinimize[Norm[f1]+Norm[f2]+Norm[f3], {x,y,z}, Method -> "RandomSearch"]] yields {0.296402, {1.32*10^-15, {x -> -2.35461*10^10, y -> 8.86433*10^9, z -> 4.16764*10^10}}}

Comment: Tho the functions have huge(!) coefficients, there is still some hope; as they are rational, extract the numerators and feed those to `NSolve[]`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. seems a good idea, tried and failed. `g1 = Numerator@Together[f1];
g2 = Numerator@Together[f2];
g3 = Numerator@Together[f3];
FindRoot[{g1 == 0, g2 == 0, g3 == 0}, {{x, 0}, {y, 0}, {z, 0}}];
{f1, f2, f3} /. %;`

Comment: @Bill It seems `NMinimize` produces some solutions very close to zero.

Comment: Well, why not choose better starting values? Look at the ones in Marco's answer, for instance.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. better starting point will help, `FindRoot[{g1 == 0, g2 == 0, 
  g3 == 0}, {{x, 0.1022}, {y, -0.6191}, {z, -4.8615}}]`, but the trick seems not helping for `NSolve`. The command hangs there as well.

Comment: If you experiment with WorkingPrecision->nn in that NMinimize you can get all kinds of values for x,y,z. Thus I question whether this is crawling down some nearly horizontal valley on the surface.

Comment: @Bill Yes, I found that as well. This may explain why the `NSolve` cannot produce output from those equations.

Comment: I think I've confirmed it is denominators getting huge that explains this. Norm[Numerator[Together[Expand[ f1]]]] (and f2 and f3) appears to dependably extract the numerators, the minima are now found close to the origin and don't crawl off to infinity with changes in WorkingPrecision, but finding a minima is now 10-100x slower and it seems more likely to get trapped in a (sometimes HUGE) local minima. And the 3 denominators are equal.

Comment: @Bill good job! I think this question may end here. Because there seems no hope to find a exact solutions of the equations, and finding a interval that contains solution seems not a easy task to do as well.

Answer (score 1):

`f1`, `f2`, and `f3` are not equations themselves, but from what you show I think that you want to find roots to those expressions.

In that case, `FindRoot` can do that VERY fast (I am using your definitions of `f1`, `f2`, `f3`):

```
solutions = FindRoot[{f1 == 0, f2 == 0, f3 == 0},
  {{x, 1*^60}, {y, 1*^60}, {z, 1*^60}},
  MaxIterations -> 1000]

(* Out: {x -> 5.25906*10^62, y -> 4.68025*10^62, z -> 5.41624*10^62} *)
```

You can then backsubstitute into the $f_i$ to confirm that indeed these values are roots for those three complicated functions:

```
{f1, f2, f3} /. solutions

(*Out: {-1.37719*10^-51, 2.93792*10^-52, 1.08335*10^-51} *)
```

Here are some timing results:

```
RepeatedTiming[FindRoot[{f1 == 0, f2 == 0, f3 == 0},
  {{x, 1*^60}, {y, 1*^60}, {z, 1*^60}},
  MaxIterations -> 1000], 10]

(* Out: {0.014, {x -> 5.25906*10^62, y -> 4.68025*10^62, z -> 5.41624*10^62}} *)
```

It is worth noting, however, that `NSolve` and `FindRoot` **solve two different problems**. This is explained well in the [Numerical Equation Solving](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalEquationSolving.html) tutorial in the documentation. `FindRoot` will find *one* instance of a root for the equation you give it, typically the closest one to your initial guess. `NSolve` will attempt to find *all* roots if possible, using numerical methods and transformation rules. Which one to use really depends on what you are trying to accomplish, of course.

Comment: I am not convinced that's an actual solution, it's just pretty close to zero given your numerical accuracy.